# How to convert numbers to currency values?

Tags: pure-function, conversion

I am trying to create a way to convert some values of numbers into currency (dollars). The example I display below takes in three random numbers between -4 and 4, and rounds them to the second decimal place. How could I create the output in $$ though? Should I try something rule based?

```
Clear[sequence];
sequence = RandomReal[{-4, 4}, 3];
Map[(N[Round[10^2 *#]/(10^2)]) &, sequence]
```

> {-3.73, 2.03, 0.31}

But I want -$3.73 and so on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cash = N[Round[10^2*#]/(10^2)] & /@ RandomReal[{-4, 4}, 3]
```

> {-3.21, 2.64, -2.6}

```
If[Sign[#] > 0, "$" <> ToString[#], 
   "-$" <> ToString[Abs[#]]] & /@ cash
```

> {"-\$3.21", "\$2.64", "-\$2.6"}

Note the output is a list of strings.

---

Or

```
q = Quantity[cash, "USDollars"]
```

> {\$-3.21, \$2.64, \$-2.6}

The output is a list of `Quantities`:

```
QuantityQ /@ q
```

> {True, True, True}

Comment: Very nice as always corey

Answer (score 3):

[Quantity](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html) and [Units](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Units.html) are your friends. One way could be:

```
Clear[sequence];
sequence = RandomReal[{-4, 4}, 3];
d = Map[(N[Round[10^2*#]/(10^2)]) &, sequence]
```

> `{3.82,3.64,0.}`

```
Quantity[d, "USD"]
```

> `{$ 3.82,$ 3.64,$ 0.}`

Comment: That's exactly the same approach as in my answer...

Comment: Great Louis. Nice methods from both you and Corey

Answer (score -1):

```
Map[$, N[Round[10^2*#]/(10^2)] & /@ RandomReal[{-4, 4}, 3]]
    (*{$[3.61], $[2.45], $[-1.79]}*)
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: not quite, but I appreciate the response! Very close to the output I was looking for. Check out the 2 other answers above